# How to start a GUI application from the terminal and return immediately?

Tags: command-line

For example, if I type `gimp` in my terminal, Gimp will launch, but it will wait for gimp to be closed before returning control to the terminal. If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> it will close Gimp. How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

place an ampersand (&) at the end of the command, e.g.:

```
gksu nautilus &
```

to start a root file manager, or in your case, to start GIMP:

```
gimp &
```

It's really as simple as that!

Comment: And run `disown` ("Remove jobs from current shell") if you wish to be able to close that terminal.