# no username and host name in terminal

Tags: command-line, nautilus

I was trying to install a program on my system and I typed `sudo nautilus`. It ran a series of lines. Now the terminal doesnt bring a new line with my username@host in the beginning. It's just a empty line.

```
sara@sara-MacBookAir:~/Downloads/cmake-3.6.1$ sudo nautilus

(nautilus:7046): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

** (nautilus:7046): CRITICAL **: Another desktop manager in use; desktop window won't be created
Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Failed to execute child process "net" (No such file or directory)
Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Failed to execute child process "net" (No such file or directory)
```

This is done but the new line doesnt start with my username and host name. how can I start a line with my username in the beginning

Comment: First **don't do that** see [Why should users never use normal sudo to start graphical applications?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-should-users-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-applications). Second, your question is essentially a duplicate of [How to start a GUI application from the terminal and return immediately?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/320416/how-to-start-a-gui-application-from-the-terminal-and-return-immediately)

Answer (score 2):

The process is still running in the 'foreground'. Freeze the process:

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>

Then type `bg` to send the process to the background. Your prompt will come back.

Or, just open a new terminal ;)

More importantly, don't use `sudo nautilus`, do `sudo -i nautilus`. Using `sudo` with graphical applications is a **really bad idea**, as explained [in answers here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-should-users-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-applications)

I would launch Nautilus as root like this:

```
sudo -i
nautilus >/dev/null 2>&1 & disown
exit
```

`sudo -i` start a root shell
`>/dev/null 2>&1` this stops any output from the program (such as the Gtk warnings that I can safely ignore) being printed to the terminal and interrupting me
`&` send the process to the background
`disown` the process is no longer a child of the shell, so will stay open when I close the shell or the terminal window
`exit` close the root shell to drop privileges (but nautilus stays open with root privilege until you close it)